# Typescript arrow function with with generics to delete an object from a array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have multiple arrays of objects in different types as follows.

```
unit:Unit[]=[{id:1,name:'unit 1']

book:Book[]=[{id:1,name:'book1']
```

To remove objects from the arrays I want to create a general function which should be an arrow function with generics and exporting from another `.ts` file. So that I can delete any arrays using that function.

I have tried like this

```
export const deleteFromArray= <T>(arr: T[], value: any) => {
  return arr.filter((val: T) => val['id'] != value)
}
```

Comment: So you are alwys using `id` as the the critera?

Comment: No. I  want to change the criteria to dynamic.

Comment: Then it gets more complicated, what if the criteria is an object that has to match?

Comment: Sounds good. Can I have an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are always using `id` as the filter critera you could `extend` your generic `T` by `{id: number}` by default.

```
export const deleteFromArray = <T extends {id: number}>(
  arr: T[],
  value: any
): T[] => {
  return arr.filter((val: T) => val.id != value);
};
```

That way you can use the function like so:

```
type Book = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

deleteFromArray<Book>([{id: 0, name: "myBook"}], 0);
```

Comment: What would be the changes if I want to change `id` as the filter criteria?

Answer (score 1):

first of all `delete` is a reserved word in JavaScript, so use a different name. The second thing is that in the `arr.filter()` method you're creating variable `val`, but you're using the same name for the argument `val`. I think name collision is happening.

Hope that helps.